# Difference, in terms of completeness, between the Dirac well and barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, potential, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I was in my undergraduate QM lecture and we just finished with the Dirac barrier. My question is as follows: We know that the [Dirac well](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=dirac+well)’s complete set of solutions requires one bound state and an infinite set of scattering states (plane waves). The solutions to the Dirac barrier are a only a set of scattering states (plane waves again). How can both sets of solutions be complete? I asked this question in lecture and was told that no one-to-one correspondence exists between the two sets of plane waves, so the comparison is improper, but I’ve been unable to find anything else on the subject.

Comment: Can you expand on your reasoning as to why you think they shouldn't be complete?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what OP asks, but the potential profile $V$ clearly matters. E.g. if $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}V(x)=\infty$, such as, the [harmonic oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator), or the [infinite well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box), then there are no scattering states at all!